# Problems with understanding instruction fine-tuning

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, large-language-models, gpt

I'm trying to read up on instruction fine-tuning, but I think I have a big misunderstanding.

As I understand, instruction datasets typically have 3 components: (a) the instruction (b) the output/response, and (c) and an optional input. Now, according to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.10792.pdf): "Based on the collected IT dataset, a pretrained model can be directly fine-tuned in a fully-supervised manner, where given the instruction and the input, the model is trained by predicting each token in the output sequentially." This makes sense to me, i.e, the response/output is the ground truth the model is expected to predict.

However, when I check many tutorials (e.g., this [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/philschmid/deep-learning-pytorch-huggingface/blob/main/training/instruction-tune-llama-2-int4.ipynb)), it seems that instructions, inputs, and outputs are all combined into a single text sample. But I can't tell from the notebook how the training now works. What is now the ground truth for the supervised training. Or is this now treated as a next-word-prediction task?

What am I missing? Or are these indeed two different approaches for instruction tuning. Sorry if those a stupid questions!